# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Restricting Search to Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that looks at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view in two databases. It looks at each column in a database and compares the attributes to the same column (actually table.column) in the other database.

The code works fine except that when I run through `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` it picks up the definitions for columns that exist in both tables and views. I need to restrict the query to look just at tables.

Can someone suggest how I might do this?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
      CASE
         WHEN src.TABLE_NAME IS NULL AND src.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
         THEN
            tgt.TABLE_NAME + '.' + tgt.COLUMN_NAME
         ELSE
            src.TABLE_NAME + '.' + src.COLUMN_NAME
      END
         AS object_name,
FROM [hq193].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS src
      FULL JOIN [GDI-193-DEV].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS tgt
         ON     src.table_name = tgt.table_name
            AND src.COLUMN_NAME = tgt.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE    src.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH != tgt.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
      OR src.DATA_TYPE != tgt.DATA_TYPE
      OR src.IS_NULLABLE != tgt.IS_NULLABLE
      OR src.NUMERIC_PRECISION != tgt.NUMERIC_PRECISION
      OR src.NUMERIC_SCALE != tgt.NUMERIC_SCALE
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` I prefer using `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`, they `JOIN` on `object_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t
 ON c.object_id = t.object_id
```

Info on views is contained in `sys.views`.

Something like:

```
;WITH db1 AS (    SELECT c.*,t.name Table_Name
                  FROM sys.columns c
                  JOIN sys.tables t
                    ON c.object_id = t.OBJECT_ID
             )
     ,db2 AS (    SELECT c.*,t.name Table_Name
                  FROM db2.sys.columns c
                  JOIN db2.sys.tables t
                    ON c.object_id = t.OBJECT_ID
             )           
SELECT CASE WHEN db1.Table_Name IS NULL AND db1.name IS NULL
              THEN db2.Table_Name + '.' + db2.name
            ELSE db1.Table_Name + '.' + db1.name
       END AS object_name
FROM  db1 
FULL JOIN  db2                           
  ON db1.Table_Name = db2.Table_Name
   AND db1.name = db2.name
WHERE db1.max_length     <>  db2.max_length
  OR  db1.system_type_id <>  db2.system_type_id
  OR  db1.is_nullable    <>  db2.is_nullable
  OR  db1.precision      <>  db2.precision
  OR  db1.scale          <>  db2.scale
```

Or you could just add a `JOIN` to `sys.tables` to your current query to weed out views:

```
SELECT 
      CASE
         WHEN src.TABLE_NAME IS NULL AND src.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
         THEN
            tgt.TABLE_NAME + '.' + tgt.COLUMN_NAME
         ELSE
            src.TABLE_NAME + '.' + src.COLUMN_NAME
      END
         AS object_name,
FROM [hq193].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS src
JOIN [hq193].sys.tables t
  ON src.table_name = t.name
      FULL JOIN [GDI-193-DEV].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS tgt
         ON     src.table_name = tgt.table_name
            AND src.COLUMN_NAME = tgt.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE    src.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH != tgt.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
      OR src.DATA_TYPE != tgt.DATA_TYPE
      OR src.IS_NULLABLE != tgt.IS_NULLABLE
      OR src.NUMERIC_PRECISION != tgt.NUMERIC_PRECISION
      OR src.NUMERIC_SCALE != tgt.NUMERIC_SCALE
```

Might need to switch which db the sys.tables `JOIN` is on.